# Sentence-Transformer Training and Validation Loss

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

I am using the Sentence-Transformers model to Fine Tune(using PyTorch) it on a custom dataset which is the same as the Semantic Text Similarity (STS) Dataset.

I am unable to get(or print) the training or validation error during training. I am trying to find how to monitor these errors during or after training, explored different documentation, and tried solutions but still unable to monitor those errors.

Below is the training part of the code. How can one know the training and validation error during the training for SBERT?

```
train_loss = losses.MultipleNegativesRankingLoss(model)
evaluator = EmbeddingSimilarityEvaluator.from_input_examples(val_set, name='sts-dev')
num_epochs = 20
warmup_steps = int(len(train_dataloader) * num_epochs * 0.1)

model.fit(train_objectives=[(train_dataloader, train_loss)],
          evaluator=evaluator,
          epochs=num_epochs,
          evaluation_steps=1000,
          warmup_steps=warmup_steps,
          show_progress_bar=True)
```

[You can see the progress bar of training for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7X2X.png)

Answer (score 2):

At this point in time, there appears to be issues [#336](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/336), [#510](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/510) and [#1021](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/1021) open on SentenceTransformers GitHub repository requesting this functionality. Some of the comments on those threads offer some intermediary solutions whilst pull request [#1606](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/pull/1606) is worked on to provide a generic framework for loss tracking.

In general, the interim solutions suggested either modify the behaviour of the [fit()](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L575) function in [SentenceTransformers.py](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py) via the loss function [passed in](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L602) to display the loss, or implement a custom evaluator based on the the [SentenceEvaluator](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/evaluation/SentenceEvaluator.py) that provides the same functionality as one of the concrete evaluators (e.g. the EmbeddingSimilarityEvaluator) but also displays/logs the loss.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a dev build that solves this issue,

pip install https://github.com/jdixosnd/sentence-transformers/archive/refs/heads/generic-logging.zip

you can write custom callback function to print your metrics,

```
loss_names = ["megabatchmargin"]
def log_callback_st(train_idx, epoch, training_steps, lr, loss):
    print({f"train/{loss_names[train_idx]}_loss": loss,
             f"train/{loss_names[train_idx]}_lr": lr,
            "train/steps": training_steps})
```

And finally call the fit method with `log_steps` and `log_callback` parameters,

```
model.fit(train_objectives=[(train_dataloader, train_loss)],log_steps=16,log_callback=log_callback_st, epochs=10)
```